# Проблема с таймингом

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Вечер добрый. Есть программа для эмуляции. Беда в том, что мне нужно ловить тайминг. Но почему-то после выхода из цикла имею очень большое значение ожидания.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <time.h>
#include <Windows.h>

double diffclock(clock_t clock1) {
    clock_t clock2 = clock();
    double diffticks = clock1 - clock2;
    double diffms = diffticks / (CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000);

    return diffms;
}


int main()
{
    int wait = 134;
    clock_t fullbetween = clock();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Sleep(wait / 5);
        cout << wait / 5 << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl << "finish in " << diffclock(fullbetween) << " ms" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Имею суммарное время ожидания 134. Мне надо прождать это время / 5 в цикле. Он верно ждёт по 26мс. Но в последнем выводе показывает время всех итераций 170ms+, хотя 26*5=130. В чём может быть проблема ?

Comment: Ох уж это время выполнения... А вы попробуйте запустить не один раз, а несколько десятков раз подряд и увидите что общее время меняется (скажем, от 120 до 320 миллисекунд). Почему, это другой вопрос. / Поэтому подобные задачи надо решать несколько другим образом. Перед циклом вычисляется время ожидания для каждого шага. При каждой итерации  перед Sleep запрашивается текущее время, сравнивается с вычисленным для данного шага и вычисляется реальная задержка.

Comment: Что за странная манера писать `diffticks / (CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000)`? А что если `CLOCKS_PER_SEC / 1000` даст вам сильно округленное значение из-за целочисленного деления? Очевидно же, что лучше написать `diffticks * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC` и избежать этой потенциальной проблемы. Непонятно также почему  `clock1 - clock2`, а не наоборот.

Comment: Запускал исходный вариант, без изменений, в VS. Запускал много много раз. Что характерно, получал всегда ровно 134 в выводе, несмотря на то, что 26 * 5 = 130.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У `Sleep` есть [гранулярность](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep?redirectedfrom=MSDN) - он будет ждать минимум указанное время, но обычно больше, округляя до приблизительно 16мс кванта. Пять раз поспали - получили 8мс*5 ~= 40мс дополнительного ожидания.

Comment: «он будет ждать минимум указанное время» — документация говорит, что он будет ждать время округлённое до точности системных часов в *произвольную* сторону (вероятней всего в одну и туже для всех измерений в данном случае)... с моими наблюдеиями это также согласуется: на ХРюшке у меня воспроизвести результат OP'а не получается — всегда или `125` или `140`.

Answer (score 0):

Потому, что у вас внутри цикла производятся вычисления, организовывается вывод на экран, а потом еще и в конце, до вычисления разницы, производится вывод.

Перепишите программу вот так

```
int main()
{
    int wait = 134;
    int swait = wait / 5;
    clock_t fullbetween = clock();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Sleep(swait);
        // cout << wait / 5 << "  ";
    }
    double diff = diffclock(fullbetween);
    cout << endl << "finish in " << diff << " ms" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

и погрешность будет пара миллисекунд

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю,
выполняем :

1. сравнение `i < 5;`
2. ждем  `26мс`
3. вывод `cout << wait / 5 << "  ";`
   Все это 5 раз.
4. выводим  `cout << endl << "finish in "` и выполняем инкремент
5. вызываем функцию
6. выполняется тело функции

   И к результату `5 * 26` еще нужно добавить  `(время на п1 и п3) * 5 + время на п4 + время на п6`  и время которое может съедать операционная система. И все это с небольшой погрешностью у вас равен `170ms`

Comment: 1.5 Вычисление `wait / 5`

Comment: Anton Shchyrov ,  да и это тоже, но данное вычисление современный компилятор  выполнит один раз, и в принципе std::endl тоже является операцией(очищает буфер и переводит на новую строку